# Append value before port number in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

I have a port number localhost:4500 in angular2, if users will sign in then, I want to change the port number to username.localhost:4500.
Ex: abc.localhost:4500. 
Can anyone please help me? Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need to create sub-domains for each user? You can better go with this pattern.. localhost:4500/username1, localhost:4500/username2..etc

Comment: But my requirement is to add username before port number.

Comment: This is part of server and hosting.. not with Angular or Any programming language... this should guide you better.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42338591/6446770