# Changing subdomain without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change change subdomain without refreshing the page? 
E.g. from `www.somedomain.com` to `aaa.somedomain.com` without full reload?

Edit: I need to switch subdomain part only so in above example `somedomain.com` stays same, only `www` is changed to `aaa`

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Is this the XY problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

If you're switching domain you will need to reload

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. The HTML5 History API can help with folders, but not domains (since the subdomain is considered a different origin, security-wise).

Comment: ANd after the edit, answer is still no. You need to redirect.

Answer (score 4):

what you are looking for is `History.pushState()`, but as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807921/html5-history-api-pushstate-from-a-domain-to-a-subdomain/14823131#14823131),

It can't be done. This is by design. There are no exceptions.

From the [Mozilla pushState documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29.C2.A0method):

> The new URL **must** be of the same origin as the current URL; **otherwise**, pushState() will throw an exception.